# Webpack doesn't split a huge vendor bundle when using barrel files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402500) to the question [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard) I was able to import multiple modules in a single declaration, exporting them like this:

###### Part of `/hooks/index.ts`

```js
export { default as useSections } from './useSections';
export { default as useArtworkEvents } from './useArtworkEvents';
export { default as useEventBusListener } from './useEventBusListener';
```

And then importing them in a component like this:

###### Part of `Packaging.tsx`

```js
import { useSections, useArtworkEvents, useEventBusListener } from 'src/hooks';
```

I’m doing the same thing in another project where there are no issues, but here I’m importing large libraries from the modules and all those libraries go into the vendor folder.

The libraries are imported like this:

###### sample of one of the hooks

```js
import { autorun, IReactionDisposer } from 'mobx';
// body of the module
// and the export in the end
export default useArtworkEvents;
```

And this is the current situation:

[image: Current Webpack Situation]

It looks like the first place where one of the files is imported (let's say `App.tsx`) is where all the libraries get loaded, even if only one should be imported (in my intentions).

I want to add that this is happening even if the components that use the libraries are loaded dynamically, through React Suspense:

###### Sample from `App.tsx`

```js
const PackagingComponent = lazy(
    () => import('src/components/PackagingComponent' /* webpackChunkName: "packaging" */)
);
```

And then

```js
<ErrorBoundary locale={props.locale}>
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
    {props.componentType === AcceptedComponentTypes.PACKAGING && (
      <DesignStackPackaging
        locale={props.locale}
        tenant={props.tenant}
      />
     )}
     {/* ...other conditions */}
  </Suspense>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

#### Solution?

If I remove the export in the index files (there are two in the project, one for common scripts and the other for hooks) and import the modules directly, the issue will go away.

###### Part of `/hooks/index.ts`

```js
export {};
```

###### Part of `Packaging.tsx`

```js
import useSections from 'src/hooks/useSections';
import useArtworkEvents from 'src/hooks/useArtworkEvents';
import useEventBusListener from 'src/hooks/useEventBusListener';
```

You can see that the issue seems to be solved:

[image: Possible solution]

So I’m asking two things:

1. Does anyone know why is this happening?
2. Is there a more convenient way of exposing modules (without adding a new line for every new import)?

I thought that maybe I could put all the modules that import large libraries in a separate folder where I don’t export them with an index file, while keeping smaller modules in some common folders where I do export them using the index file, but I don’t like the solution as it doesn't feel consistent, and a co-worker which is not aware may take the issue back.

For context I also add the Webpack Split Chunks configuration:

```js
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
  name: true,
},
```

(BTW the same happens if `name` is set to `false`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after posting the question, I've found this other question in the **related** section: [Barrel file and Tree Shaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527907/barrel-file-and-tree-shaking), which made me understand that the `index` files that I'm referring to have a name, which is **barrel files**, and that there are various articles on the subject.

[This article](https://tsh.io/blog/how-to-keep-your-lighthouse-score-high-in-next-js-applications-a-checklist/) for example advises not to use barrel files as they create issues with tree-shaking.

Luckily I've found [this Github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557) (in the **Next.js** repository) with the [solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557#issuecomment-994278512) to my specific problem.

The solution is to turn off **side effects** for the barrel files, so that **Webpack** will not load the whole folder every time you need one single module.

So in my case the relevant part of the **Webpack** configuration becomes:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules...
      {
        test: [/src\/common\/index.ts/i, /src\/hooks\/index.ts/i],
        sideEffects: false,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Everything else stays the same.

Finally I would like to quote a part of [this reply](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557#issuecomment-1309240211) from the same user which gave the solution:

> Barrel files are effectively an API. A specific interface that distinguishes private vs public code. It especially makes sense in a monorepo with local packages. The same concept (why do packages have a specific import interface) pros/cons applies to monorepo packages.

So in the end I'm thankful that I've been able to keep barrel files without having to import every module separately.

Comment: I’ve found an article with more details on the same situation: https://renatopozzi.me/articles/your-nextjs-bundle-will-thank-you