# Jest - looking at non-related codes

Tags: typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm working on a sample ExpressJs application written with Typescript in which I tried to implement Jest. I have a service class which I want to test but it seems like Jest is looking at the wrong source codes when I run the actual test.

[image: Image of error]

If you look at the stack trace of the error, it seems it is executing a lot more than it should. I'm only testing `auth.service.ts` but it seems it is scanning a lot more. Below is my `auth.service.ts` file.

```
import { generateUuid, isPasswordMatching, redisClient } from '../utils';
import { getUserService } from './user.service';

class AuthService {
  private userService = getUserService();

  async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<string | null> {
    const user = await this.userService.getUserByUsername(username);

    if (!user) return null;

    if (!(await isPasswordMatching(password, user.password))) return null;

    if (!user.token) {
      user.token = generateUuid();
      await user.save();
    }

    await redisClient.set(user.token, user.userId);

    return user.token;
  }
}

const authService = new AuthService();

export const getAuthService = (): AuthService => {
  return authService;
};
```

And here is my test file which is what I'm trying to execute.

```
import { getAuthService } from '../../src/services/auth.service';

const authService = getAuthService();

test('auth service init', () => {
  expect(authService).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

**UPDATE: posting my `auth.route.ts` file as well**

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';
import { getAuthService } from '../services';
import { loginSchema, validateParams } from '../validators';

const authService = getAuthService();

export const authRoute = (router: Router) => {
  router.post('/login', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { data, error } = await validateParams(req.body, loginSchema);

    if (error) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: error });
      return;
    }

    const token = await authService.login(data.username, data.password);

    if (!token) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: `Invalid credentials.` });
      return;
    }

    res.status(200).send({ token });
  });
};
```

Comment: Show auth.route.ts as that is where the issue was encountered. Jest is running the correct code based on your imports.

Comment: @morganney can you explain why jest is running my auth.route.ts? based on my imports, there is nothing there importing my route. i'll update my post and add your requested code.

Comment: @morganney I've updated my post and added my auth.route.ts file as requested.

Comment: Upon further reading, looks like this issue is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490472/barrel-files-webpack-and-jest

Comment: The file you are testing depends on it. Obvious.

Comment: No it doesn't. Auth service does not depende on auth route. The issue is with the barrel files which jest crawls when it looks on it. So, not obvious.

Comment: Now it appears you may have a cycle in your dependency graph. Do you have index files re-exporting modules? What is in utils/index? Stop blaming things on jest, it is helping you find bugs in your structure.

Comment: I'm not in any way blaming jest. I just didn't know that jest crawls on exported files on the barrel files. Anyway, I solved the issue by removing my barrel files and importing sole files on my codes.